# Pass every loop variable to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The images are stored inside separate folders.

Both the folders and the images are saved in the database. In my gallery page, they are shown from the database in two steps.

1. The folders are retrieved from the `db` and listed in the gallery page
2. while on-click of a folder, the images are listed.

So far, I have passed the data from the database to the view. The following is my controller code.

```
function image_show() {
    $this->load->model('gallery_model');
    $data['folder_info'] = $this->gallery_model->get_folder_names();
}
```

and my view code is as follows:

```
<?php foreach($folder_info as $show){ ?>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="font-size: 100px;" aria-hidden="true" onclick="imageslide(' .$show['folder_name'] .');" ></a>    
<?php } ?>
```

From the above code, the folders are listed in the gallery page.
I am struck while trying to pass the `$show['folder_name']` from the php `foreach` loop so that I can generate a image slider.
My script is

```
function imageslide(name) {
    alert(name);
}
```

The error shown to me is

```
gallery:194 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Kindly help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `$show['folder_name']` variable inside a php block, *i.e.*:

```
<?php foreach($folder_info as $show){ ?>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="font-size: 100px;" aria-hidden="true" onclick="imageslide('<?php echo $show['folder_name'] ?>');" ></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How should I pass the `$show['folder_name']` to the data in `ajax call` inside the `<script>` after the onclick function..?